# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') when trying to access req.user.id

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

Below is my dashboard controller function

```
exports.dashboardPage = async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        console.log(req.user.id) 
        const stories = await Story.find({user: req.user.id}).lean();
    
        const token = req.cookies.token
        const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const userName = payload.userName
        console.log({title: 'DASHBOARD', layout: 'dashboard', msg: userName});
        res.render('dashboard', {title: 'DASHBOARD', layout: 'dashboard', msg: userName, stories});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.render('error/500')
    }
};
```

and this is my database story model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const StorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'public',
    enum: ['public', 'private',]    
  },
  user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema)
```

i am logging in alright because i added the command in my login controller to check but it keeps redirecting me to the error page and gives the error below
and am using express handlebars templating engine

logged in successfully
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: Please search this site for `[node.js] cannot read property of undefined`. This question has been asked and answered literally hundreds (if not thousands) of times here before - surely one of those will give you an idea where to look to solve the problem.